# Python arguments cuts at < when reading from command line

Tags: python, command-line-arguments

I got a script that is supposed to take the time it takes to execute a `python`-script. For simplicity I just supply the actual command I want to execute as arguments in the commandline.

Say I call:

```
python time.py python ratatosk.py < input.txt
```

Here everything after `python time.py` is the actual command I want to execute.

However, when reading the `sys.argv` with this:

```
print 'Number of arguments:', len(sys.argv), 'arguments.'
print 'Argument List:', str(sys.argv)
```

It only returns:

```
Number of arguments: 3 arguments.
Argument List: ['time.py', 'python', 'ratatosk.py']
```

Where did the rest of the arguments go? It looks like `<` somehow stripped it away.

I am running Python Python 2.7.3 (v2.7.3:70274d53c1dd, Apr  9 2012, 20:52:43) on a MacBook Pro.

Comment: The `<` character has a special meaning at OS level and is interpreted before the arguments are being passed to your program. Best to choose something else for an argument.

Comment: I would suggest you do something like this `<<` or `<=`, just to escape the `cmd` interpreter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to escape the < sign. 
try calling:

```
python time.py python ratatosk.py \< input.txt
```

it might be better to use a different character than < so that running this command is easier

Answer (score 0):

You are encountering [shell redirection](http://linuxcommand.org/lts0060.php)

The `<` character has a special meaning to the shell.  It will cause the program being invoked to read from whatever follows rather than the default `stdin` (usually the keyboard).

Python is only concerned with reading from `stdin`, regardless of where that comes from.  It should't show up in `sys.argv`.

In your example, `input.txt` is likely a substitute for a user entering data into your program and your usage is correct.

Here is a short example:

**echo.py**

```
text = raw_input()
print text
```

**input.txt**

```
hello from the file
```

**example runs**

```
$ python echo.py 
hello from the keyboard
hello from the keyboard
$ python echo.py < input.txt
hello from the file
```

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to the UNIX Shell, the symbol '<' is considered to be a redirection. This means the standard input will originate from a file input.txt on disk.

Since the symbol is special, the shell converts the specified command and what reaches the kernel is a modified command that does not contain the '<'.

You can escape the '<' by adding the \ before it, so that it does not come across as a special character to the shell and is eventually passed to your program as system arguments.